# Does anyone have a python code to calculate mass weighted schlitter entropy

Tags: python-2.7, matrix, entropy

I have generated an ascii file (dat file of size (1407675×3) covariance matrix of size (2055×2055) from gromacs and want to calculate the entropy using the schlitter equation, `S=Kb/2*ln det|1 + (Kb*e*e*matrix/hbar*hbar|`

But I am getting strange values, could anyone already have a code please share or someone can modify (or check)the code below is much appreciated.

```
 import sys, os
 import numpy as np   # Import numpy for dot products etc
 import numpy.testing as npt # Import numpy.testing for comparing numbers
 import pmx # Import pmx classes
 import math # Import maths classes (floor)
 from numpy.linalg import det


 sigma = numpy.loadtxt('covar_fit.dat')
 hbar = 1.054571628e-34 #Joules seconds
 T = 310.0 # Kelvin
 Kb = 1.3806504e-23 #Joules/Kelvin
 Euler = 2.71828
 matrix = np.resize(sigma,(2055,2055))
 k = np.identity(2055)
 mat = ((Kb*T*Euler*Euler)*matrix)/(hbar*hbar)
 m = np.array(mat)+ np.array(k)
 sign,logdet = np.linalg.slogdet(m)
 (sign, logdet)
 det = logdet
 entropy = Kb*0.5*det
 print (entropy)
```

Answer (score 0):

THere is a bug in your code - `e` in equation is not an exponent (2.71828), but electron charge.

e<sup>2</sup>/(hbar*c) ~ 1/137 (aka fine-structure constant)